Error while exporting Remotion dev video using renderMedia
I am creating a video using remotion dev, I am able to create it but when i try to export it, it fails with below error. I am getting this error in win (local) and vercel both.
I have installed below packages of remotion in package.json

"@remotion/cli": "4.0.213",
"@remotion/player": "4.0.213",
"@remotion/renderer": "4.0.213",

"use client"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {
    Dialog,
    DialogContent,
    DialogDescription,
    DialogHeader,
    DialogTitle,
    DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog"
import { Player } from '@remotion/player';
import RemotionVideo from './RemotionVideo';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { db } from '@/configs/db';
import { VideoData } from '@/configs/schema';
import { eq } from 'drizzle-orm';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import axios from "axios";
import ffmpegPath from 'ffmpeg-static';

function PlayerDialog({playVideo, videoId}) {

    const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(true);
    const [videoData, setVideoData] = useState();
    const [durationInFrame, setDurationInFrame] = useState(100);
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
        setOpenDialog(!openDialog);
        videoId && GetVideoData()
    }, [playVideo, videoId])

    const GetVideoData = async () => {
        const result = await db.select().from(VideoData)
        .where(eq(VideoData.id, videoId));

        setVideoData(result[0]);
        console.log('video data '+videoData)
        console.log('video data '+result[0])
    }
    const handleExport = async (videoId, remotionVideo) => {
      const ffmpegExecutable = process.env.FFMPEG_PATH; // Use the ffmpegPath variable directly
      console.log('FFmpeg Path:', ffmpegPath);
      const resp = await axios.post('/api/export-video', {
        videoId: videoId,
        video: remotionVideo
      });

      console.log('audio script ' + resp)

    };
    return (
        <Dialog open={openDialog}>
            <DialogContent className='bg-white flex flex-col items-center'>
                <DialogHeader>
                    <DialogTitle className='text-3xl font-bold my-5'>Your video is ready</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogDescription>
                        <Player
                            component={RemotionVideo}
                            durationInFrames={Number(durationInFrame.toFixed(0))}
                            compositionWidth={300}
                            compositionHeight={450}
                            fps={30}
                            play={false}
                            loop={false}
                            controls={true}
                            inputProps={{
                                ...videoData,
                                setDurationInFrame:(frameValue)=>setDurationInFrame(frameValue)

                            }}

                        />
                        <div className='flex gap-10 mt-10'>
                            <Button variant="ghost" onClick={()=>{setOpenDialog(false)}}>Cancel</Button>
                            <Button onClick={() => handleExport("RemotionVideo", {RemotionVideo})}>Export</Button>
                        </div>
                    </DialogDescription>
                </DialogHeader>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>

    )
}

export default PlayerDialog

./node_modules/@remotion/renderer/dist/compositor/get-executable-path.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@remotion/compositor-linux-arm64-musl'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@remotion/renderer/dist/index.js
./app/api/export-video/route.jsx
./node_modules/@remotion/renderer/dist/compositor/get-executable-path.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@remotion/compositor-linux-arm64-gnu'
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@remotion/renderer/dist/index.js
./app/api/export-video/route.jsx
> Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

